# iOS 7 + Auto Layout: Strange UIImageView behaviour

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, storyboard, autolayout

I've got a strange UIImageView behaviour:

I've got a UIViewController with an embedded UIImageView and a close button. Very basic stuff, done a thousand times. I didn't use Auto Layout that much in the past, but another view controller in the same Storyboard has nearly the same config and doesn't appear as strange as this specific one.

In my Storyboard the Controller looks like that:

[image: Storyboard]

...and on the device it looks like that:

[image: Device]

That image is 1024x768, so it should be filled to the bounds. Content mode in the image view is Aspect fill. When i dismiss the view, i can see that the upper part of the image view must be hidden at the top with some negative Y or something.

I need Auto Layout in this storyboard, because it's an iPhone + iPad App with both orientations.

Has someone hat a behaviour like that before?

Thank you!

**Edit:**

Here is the layout panel:

[image: Layout Panel]

Comment: Could you post the constraints applied to your UIImageView (a screenshot of the layout panel in XCode should suffice).

Comment: What's the yellow warning telling?

Comment: Maybe the easiest way could be to make your project available via github or like. So that we could check quickly?

Comment: @juanignaciosl the yellow warning is from another view and has nothing to do with this problem

Comment: @Zedenem Since this is a customers project I cannot make it available online :(

Comment: Well, it makes all of this hard to answer then. You could try removing the `Align Center...` constraints because they are not useful. Then you can check all the other constraints in details, verifying that all their constants are `0`. If this doesn't work, then you will have to post the details of each constraints. I will try to build you an example project in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry that I have to say this, but it was, as you certainly thought, my own fault.

The problem was that I made a photo with the iPad, and the iPad can be used in both orientations in this app. The photo was taken and was then used for an own view that allows the user to put annotations on the image. 
The image gets then saved, and that was were the problem occured: I call

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
```

The landscape image was now taken into a portrait frame. After adjusting this and only allowing portrait mode, everything worked well.

Thanks anyways for your answers. And sorry for asking a question when the problem was another one and my own fault.

Answer (score 1):

First, get rid of the alignment constraints, they are not needed if you're already anchoring your view to every side with a set distance.
Second, check the mode property of your UIImageView in the interface builder. If the image was not big enough and you had it set for "TOP" instead of, say, "aspect fill", you'd see something like this even though the view is actually covering the whole screen.